# Grafana: How to display a timeseries in different style based on condition

Tags: time-series, grafana

I have an array of data points which consists of elements. Each element has a value and a corresponding date. The date signifies the value of the element at a certain time of the day.

The array contains the elements from date ranging from 24hours in the past (known values) and 24 hours in the future (predicted values). I can easily plot this using a simple visualization in Grafana.

However, I would like to show the plot for the past dates as a solid line. And the plot for the future dates as a dashed line.

Could you please help figure this out?

Comment: Can you add a field into your time series to distinguish between known and predicted values?

Comment: The array is received as a payload after calling a REST API. Apart from the values and the timestamp, it has many more fields. I would prefer not to add something in it even after making a copy of it since these API calls are used to get the data in range ranging from a single day to several weeks possibly couple of months too. This could be huge overhead.

Comment: Problem here is to distinguish between real and projected data: if they are separted into two different time series visualization config is easy. If only way you can do it right now is by the fact that timestamp is less or more than now - then I don't think this is achievable in vanilla Grafana. Maybe some plugins provide such functionality, but I'm not aware of those too (though you can always write your own).